# How to reference cells from DBF with python?

Tags: python, dbf

Lets say I have a DBF file with data as shown:

Header1  Header2

1           5

2           6

3           7

4           8

And I would like to point to cell A2, add it to B2, create a new column on C titled Header3 and write the answer to C3, how do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, dbf files are not spreadsheets.  Thinking of them as spreadsheet cells is not helpful.

The answer to your question depends on what package/module you are using to access this file.  If you are [using mine](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf) it would look something like this:

```
import dbf

my_table = dbf.Table('/path/and/filename')

with my_table:
    my_table.add_fields('header3 N(3,0)')

    for record in dbf.Process(my_table):
        record.header3 = record.header1 + record.header2
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for, thank you.  Lets say i wanted to create a 4th column titled header4 and i want to enter the string 'this number is greater than 9' or 'this number is less than 9'.  It is creating the new column however not writing any data to that column.  Do these statements need to be written a different way other than:



if record.header3 > 9:
    record.header4 = 'this number is greater than 9'

Comment: nevermind I figured out that portion.  It seems i'm having an issue with if statements where the values in the dbf are text strings.  Do I need to write that a certain way so python will interpret correctly?

Example,

if record.site == 'home'